# Backbone.js render collection in View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a Backbone Collection that I'm trying to render in the View.  The JSON data seems correct, however I can't access the values from within the view.

Here's the basic collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'BaseModel'], function(Backbone, BaseModel) {

    var BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

         model: BaseModel,
         url: "/collection/get?json=true",

         initialize: function() {}
    });

    return BaseCollection;

});
```

Here's the View:

```
define(['backbone', 'BaseCollection'], function(Backbone, BaseCollection) {

    var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#baseContainer'),
        template: _.template($('#baseTemplate').html()),

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this);
            this.collection = new BaseCollection();
            this.collection.bind('all', this.render, this);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function() {   

            //This returns 3 objects which is correct based on the JSON data being returned from the server
            console.log(this.collection.toJSON());

            var html = this.template(this.collection.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(html);
            return this;
        },

    });

    return BaseView;

});
```

I think I need to iterate through `this.render` for each model within the collection.  But, I'm not sure, because it shouldn't 'render' until it completes all iterations.

Any suggestions would be great! Thank you!

Comment: can you show us your template? My guess is you need to modify the parameter you're passing to `this.template()`, or modify the template itself. You can use `collection.each` within your template to loop through all models in the collection (however, it's recommended to create sub-views for each model if you'll be binding lots of model-specific events)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your template access to the models via name. When you do this:

```
var html = this.template(this.collection.toJSON());
```

You end up passing an array to the `template` function, which normally expects a context object (name/value pairs). Try this:

```
var html = this.template({collection: this.collection});
```

Then in your template you can iterate through them using the `collection.each` iterator function or any of the underscore utility methods for iteration/filtering/map/etc. I also recommend NOT using toJSON when giving your template access to the collection as it makes your data dumber and harder to work with. `toJSON` is best left for when you are making HTTP requests.